# All the tests of the same category show up as only one test result w/ TestNG in Intellij and I'd like it not to happen. How?

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, testng

I have been developing a project which contains a `TestLauncher` class that'll read a given directory and for each file it contains, run it against my tool and yield the results.

So, when coding in Eclipse, it would show up one result for each test (as expected). Today I've been toying with Intellij, and I've decided to try to run and code a bit of this project in Intellij.

When trying to run the tests, though, it seems to be only showing up 2 results instead of the 100+ it should. Although I am sure it is running the full suite, it seems to be folding all the results of a given category in a single result. That means that if I have at least one failing test in each category, it shows up as a "failed test".

I guess this must not be a bug, but rather some configuration that I am not aware about and that is on by default in Intellij but not in Eclipse. Could anyone explain what might be going on?

Edit: I am using the latest Intellij (downloaded one of these days).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is simply a difference in the way the Eclipse and IDEA plug-ins are implemented. I implemented the Eclipse plug-in to be pretty clever in its display, so it will show different things depending on various factors such as the presence of a toString() method in your test class or whether your test class implements org.testng.ITest.

I suggest you ask this question on the IDEA forums and if you don't get any response, feel free to email the testng-users list and I can put you in touch with the JetBrains engineer in charge of the TestNG plug-in.

Comment: I've been looking at your faq. Wouldn't it have something to do with fileFragmentationLevel? I'm terrible with configuration files, so I couldn't actually test this.

Answer (score 0):

The IntelliJ-IDEA TestNG Plugin has a filter symbol called "Hide Passed" above the output Test Results. You can toggle that to display all tests, including the passed ones.